# Control the spacing between characters in a long equation

Tags: spacing, equations

While writing long equations in different math environments, I noticed that, as far as horizontal spacing is concerned, environments can be divided into two groups.

**First group**, the spacing between characters is independent from equation length: `gather`, `align`, `alignat`, `flalign`, `eqnarray`.

**Second group**, the space depends on equation length: `\[ \]`, `displaymath`, `equation`.

```
\begin{gather*} a\cdot b = (2\cdot n+1)\cdot (2\cdot m+1) = 4\cdot n\cdot m+2\cdot n+2\cdot m+1 \end{gather*}
\[ a\cdot b = (2\cdot n+1)\cdot (2\cdot m+1) = 4\cdot n\cdot m+2\cdot n+2\cdot m+1 \]
```

[image]

```
\begin{gather*} a\cdot b = (2\cdot n+1)\cdot (2\cdot m+1) = 4\cdot n\cdot m+2\cdot n+2\cdot m+1 = 2\cdot (2\cdot n\cdot m+n+m)+1 \end{gather*}
\[ a\cdot b = (2\cdot n+1)\cdot (2\cdot m+1) = 4\cdot n\cdot m+2\cdot n+2\cdot m+1 = 2\cdot (2\cdot n\cdot m+n+m)+1 \]
```

[image]

Using `\[ \]` the space between characters is reduced in long equations, while using `\gather` the space remains unchanged.

What are the reasons for this? Moreover, is it possibile to let the second group environments have fixed space between characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same as comparing `hello world` and `\mbox{hello world}` boxing typically involves freezing space and stopping it stretching. The AMS alignments need to box and measure lots of things internally to get the alignments to align...

In math mode a brace group has the same effect so  `\[{...}\]` would set all space to its natural length (which might cause an over-full box) whereas `\[...\]` allows some flexibility.